# copy SharePoint file including version history in Windows SharePoint Service 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, versioning, copy-and-paste

Is there a way to COPY a SharePoint file including its version history from the Windows SharePoint Service 3.0? I have a file I want to copy but it did not carry over all previous version histories when I copy it. Appreciate for the idea!

Comment: For migration I strongly suggest using metavis from metavistech. It is very easy to use..

Comment: Where are you moving it to? Same site, farm?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the versioning in the destination list matches that of the source list and then just use Content and Structure to move/copy the file.

Comment: I am not familiar with SharePoint. Where is Content and Structure locate? I look in Site Action and Setting pulldown list but I do not find the Content and Structure anywhere. Thanks for your response!

Comment: go to `Site Actions - Site Settings - Modify All Site Settings` and look for "Content and Structure" under "Site Administration"

Comment: WSS doesn't have Content and Structure, that's a Server feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the Content Migration API, which btw. is used by the site manager (Manage Content and Structure on a publishing site), but it will require you to write a bit of code.

Stefan Gossner has a nice blog post about the API: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/08/30/deep-dive-into-the-sharepoint-content-deployment-and-migration-api-part-1.aspx

You can find lots of good related Q&As on stackexchange when you search for 'Content Migration API'.